# Simple form gem - Can't destroy comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im making a Reddit Clone and have just added comments.

Everything seems to work except i can't destroy a comment.

When i click Destroy it takes me to an page where i can view the comment. Yo can see the page here http://postimg.org/delete/ehlqrvngq/.

Here is my server when i click Destroy
http://postimg.org/delete/equ2hefk8/

Here is my _comments.html.erb

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
    <div class="comments_wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <p class="lead"><%= comment.body %></p>
            <p><small>Submitted <strong><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</strong> by <%= comment.user.name %></small></p>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <% if comment.user == current_user -%>
                <%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-default" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Any clues?

Thanks

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments

  devise_for :users

  resources :links do
    member do
      get "like",    to: "links#upvote"
      get "dislike", to: "links#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end
  root "links#index"
```

Comment: Instead of call `destroy` method it is calling `show` method from your output I see this so please post `routes.rb`

Comment: Make sure you have <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %> somewhere in you layout.

Comment: I have just added routes.rb to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `method: :delete` is not working. Adding `method: :delete` should change your link to make a DELETE request, but is looks like it's performing a GET request.

Rails has some javascript magic for changing the request type. Did you include

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

in your application.js?

Comment: Yes its there

//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

Comment: do you use `turbolink` ?

Comment: No i never heard of turbolink

Comment: and you did include the application.js to your layout? like Donates suggested?

Comment: No i did. Im not sure what he means about that?

Answer (score 1):

Check your routes

It should be

```
  resources :links do
    member do
      get "like",    to: "links#upvote"
      get "dislike", to: "links#downvote"
    end
  end

  resources :comments
```

and also

Make sure you have `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` somewhere in you layout

Now it should work

Comment: Thanks. I just did all that. Still the same problem coming up in my server

Comment: did you push the changes into server and restart it?

Comment: O its all done locally. Currently not online.

Still the same problem after i did everything you said. Its weird.

Comment: you have to push the changes to the server after edit the routes.rb you have to push it. also please make soure your royutes.rb looks like wrong in your picture

Comment: `routes.rb` looks wrong it`resource :comments` should be outside the links scope

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to add  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %> to Layouts>application.html.erb

Comment: There is a comments resource outside the link scope. The routes are fine